# Sorting vs Linear search for finding min/max

Tags: perl, sorting, complexity-theory

Recently, I came across the following piece of code in perl that returns the minimum numeric value among all passed arguments.

```
return 0 + ( sort { $a <=> $b } grep { $_ == $_ } @_ )[0];
```

I usually use simple linear search to find the min/max in a list, which for me seems to be simple and adequately optimal. Is the above code in any way better than simple linear search? Anything to do with perl in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O() doesn't say anything about how long an algorithm takes. For example, all else being equal, I'd always choose Algorithm 2 among the following two:

- Algorithm 1: O(2*N + 1000 days) = O(N)
- Algorithm 2: O(5*N + 100 ms) = O(N log N)

O() specifies how the time the algorihm takes *scales* as the size of the input increases. (Well, it can be used for any resources, not just time.) Since the earlier two answers only talk in terms of O(), they are useless.

If you want to know how fast an algorithm which algorithm is better for an input of a given size, you'll need to benchmark them.

In this case, it looks like [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil)'s `min` is *always* significantly better.

```
$ perl x.pl 10
           Rate  sort LUmin
sort  1438165/s    --  -72%
LUmin 5210584/s  262%    --

$ perl x.pl 100
           Rate  sort LUmin
sort   129073/s    --  -91%
LUmin 1485473/s 1051%    --

$ perl x.pl 1000
          Rate  sort LUmin
sort    6382/s    --  -97%
LUmin 199698/s 3029%    --
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark  qw( cmpthese );
use List::Util qw( min );

my %tests = (
   'sort'  => 'my $x = ( sort { $a <=> $b } @n )[0];',
   'LUmin' => 'my $x = min @n;',
);

$_ = 'use strict; use warnings; our @n; ' . $_
   for values %tests;

local our @n = map rand, 1..( $ARGV[0] // 10 );
cmpthese(-3, \%tests);
```

Comment: Wow that is a comprehensive explanation! What technique does List::Util::min use to compute the minimum value?

Comment: @Sanjay, It's a linear search written in C.

Answer (score 2):

You are right.  If you do not need sorted data for any other purpose, the simple linear search is fastest.  To do its job, a sort would have to look at each datum at least once, anyway.

Only when the sorted data would be useful for other purposes -- or when I didn't care about run time, power usage, heat dissipation, etc. -- would I sort data to find the minimum and maximum values.

Now, @SimeonVisser is correct.  The sort does have *O(n*log(n)).*  **This is not as much slower than *O(n)* as many programmers imagine that it were.**  In practical cases of interest, the overhead of managing the sort's balanced binary tree (or other such structure) probably matters about as much as the *log(n)* factor does.  So, one needn't shrink in horror from the prospect of sorting!  However, the linear search is still faster:  you are quite right about this.

Moreover, @DavidO adds such an insightful comment that I would quote it here in his own words:

> A linear search is also an easier algorithm to generalize. A linear search could easily (and relatively efficiently) be disk based for large data sets, for example. Whereas doing a disk based sort becomes relatively expensive, and even more complex if the field sizes aren't
>   normalized.

Comment: A linear search is also an easier algorithm to generalize.  A linear search could easily (and relatively efficiently) be disk based for large data sets, for example.  Whereas doing a disk based sort becomes relatively expensive, and even more complex if the field sizes aren't normalized.

Comment: Everything else being equal, O(N log N) is 10x slower than O(N) when N = 1000. That's not a little. Of course, the real answer is probably that O() is completely irrelevant to the OP's question, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @ikegami:  You are correct.  However, programmers are notoriously misled by the *O()* notation, which is the point I was trying to make.  Algebraically, *log(n)* has order zero -- exactly zero, just as a constant like 1 has an algebraic order of zero.  Why?  Because of L'Hospital's rule; or, if you prefer, because *log(n)/n^epsilon* converges for positive *epsilon,* and diverges for negative *epsilon,* even if *epsilon* is tiny.  It is worth considering how much worse *O(sqrt(n))* is than *O(log(n)).*  Indeed, *O(log(n))* more resembles *O(1)* than many programmers believe.

Answer (score 0):

Linear search is O(*n*) for obvious reasons. Sorting is O(*n* log *n*) (see [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) in Perl documentation). So yes, linear search is indeed faster in terms of complexity. This does not only apply to Perl but to any programming language that implements these algorithms.

As with many problems, there are multiple ways to solve it and there are also multiple ways to obtain the min/max of a list. Conceptually I would say that linear search is better when you only want the min or max of a list as the problem does not call for sorting.

Comment: s/is indeed faster in terms of complexity/indeed scales better as the size of the input increases/. O(N) doesn't tell you anything about speed. An O(N) algorithm could take 1200 days to process 100 elements (2*N + 1000 days), for example.